# Identifying the elements of the dihedral group of a hexagon from SageMath.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, sagemath

I defined the dihedral group with $n=6$ in SageMath as follows:

`D6 = DihedralGroup(6)`

I'm trying to list the elements by the convention of my algebra text books where $r$ is $60 ^{\circ}$ clockwise rotation and $s$ is reflection along the $y$-axis.

I'm trying to determine which symmetry is which.

`D6.cayley_table(names = ["1","r4","r2","r5","r3","r","sr","sr5", "sr3","s","sr4","sr2"])`

But the Cayley table this outputs isn't correct. What's the proper order of listing.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Is this a mathematical question about the finite dihedral group $D_6$, or is this entirely a question about syntax in SageMath and how to get it to produce a certain desired output? If it's the latter, then I recommend that you go ask over at https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/

Comment: The second block of code I have above; the list of symbols I have assigned to the name attribute? It's supposed to be that 1 is the identity and r is 60 degree rotation and so on... that exact list and its order will be used to label the row and columns of the table as well as the elements inside. I just want the order to be accurate but it isn't. Example r5 * r5 gives r in my table when it should be r10 = (r6)(r4) = 1(r4) = r4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to generate the list of names that you want, then get the corresponding cayley table.

I will first describe a general answer that works for any dihedral group $D_n$, where we take $r$ to be the rotation counterclockwise by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ radians, and $s$ to be reflection in the $x$-axis.

The reason we take this choice is that sage represents $D_n$ internally as the permutations of the vertices of the regular $n$-gon whose vertices are given by the $n$-th roots of unity. So, you will always have a reflection in the $x$-axis, but not necessarily in the $y$-axis (unless $n$ is even).

So, lets start by defining the dihedral group of size $n$. I will use $n = 6$ as an example.

```
n = 6
D = DihedralGroup(n)
```

Now, we grab the elements corresponding to $r$ and $s$ out of this group.

```
rlist = [(i + 1) % n if (i + 1) > n else (i + 1) for i in range(1,n + 1)]
r = D(rlist)
r
```

> $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$

And similarly for $s$:

```
slist = [((1 - i) % n) + 1 for i in range(1, n + 1)]
s = D(slist)
s
```

> $(2, 6)(3, 5)$

Now, we use this to make a list of names and a corresponding list of elements as follows:

```
names = [None]*(2 * n)
elements = [None]*(2 * n)
for i in range(0, n):
    n1 = "e" if i == 0 else ("r" if i == 1 else "r" + str(i))
    n2 = "s" if i == 0 else "sr" + str(i)
    names[i] = n1
    names[i + n] = n2
    elements[i] = r^i
    elements[i + n] = s * r^i
```

The resulting lists are as follows:

```
names = ['e', 'r', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5', 's', 'sr1', 'sr2', 'sr3', 'sr4', 'sr5'],
```

and the corresponding list of elements:

```
elements = [(), (1,2,3,4,5,6), (1,3,5)(2,4,6), (1,4)(2,5)(3,6), (1,5,3)(2,6,4),
            (1,6,5,4,3,2), (2,6)(3,5), (1,2)(3,6)(4,5), (1,3)(4,6),(1,4)(2,3)(5,6),
            (1,5)(2,4), (1,6)(2,5)(3,4)].
```

We now make the Cayley table using these names and elements:

```
D.cayley_table(names, elements),
```

Giving as output the cayley table

```
  *    e   r  r2  r3  r4  r5   s sr1 sr2 sr3 sr4 sr5
   +------------------------------------------------
  e|   e   r  r2  r3  r4  r5   s sr1 sr2 sr3 sr4 sr5
  r|   r  r2  r3  r4  r5   e sr5   s sr1 sr2 sr3 sr4
 r2|  r2  r3  r4  r5   e   r sr4 sr5   s sr1 sr2 sr3
 r3|  r3  r4  r5   e   r  r2 sr3 sr4 sr5   s sr1 sr2
 r4|  r4  r5   e   r  r2  r3 sr2 sr3 sr4 sr5   s sr1
 r5|  r5   e   r  r2  r3  r4 sr1 sr2 sr3 sr4 sr5   s
  s|   s sr1 sr2 sr3 sr4 sr5   e   r  r2  r3  r4  r5
sr1| sr1 sr2 sr3 sr4 sr5   s  r5   e   r  r2  r3  r4
sr2| sr2 sr3 sr4 sr5   s sr1  r4  r5   e   r  r2  r3
sr3| sr3 sr4 sr5   s sr1 sr2  r3  r4  r5   e   r  r2
sr4| sr4 sr5   s sr1 sr2 sr3  r2  r3  r4  r5   e   r
sr5| sr5   s sr1 sr2 sr3 sr4   r  r2  r3  r4  r5   e
```

Now, you mentioned wanting to have $s$ be the reflection in the $y$-axis instead. The exact same code above will work, we just have to change $s$ to

```
s = D([4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5]),
```

however as you will note if you try this, the Cayley table doesn't change. The reason for this is that no matter what reflection $t = sr^i$ you pick, you have $t^2 = 1$ and $(tr)^2 = (sr^{i + 1})^2 = 1$, so any choice will give the same (isomorphic/equivalent) presentation of $D_6$ hence the same Cayley table (and more generally for any $D_n$).

Comment: Afraid not, r*r gives the identity with this arrangement.

Comment: I'm just noting the elements in the leading diagonal of the table output.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. For me it returns $r^2$ as expected.

Comment: In response to your edit: Yes! It is different. Wait...which version of sage are you using? Mine is 9.4

Comment: A really old one it seems, 8.3.

Comment: For the idea to find the right names, $r$ should correpond to the permutation $(1, 2, 3, 4,5,6)$ in the list, while $s$ should correspond to $(1 4)(2 3)(5 6)$ if you reflect in the $y$-axis (if you label your vertices counterclockwise, starting with $1$ on the right side of the $x$-axis). The rest you can find by just multiplying and figuring out what the resulting permutation is. It's a bit manual, but I don't see any easier way.

Comment: Right, I followed that much in my understanding. Even wrote it out on paper...

Comment: I mean, considering that the most obvious way to do this in sage seems to be manually multiplying things out, I suppose you might as well just write it out on paper, since it doesn't seem to easily generalize (unless there's a pattern to the order of the elements in `D6.list()`), I'll update my sage version to the most recent one and then take another look at it, so I will update this answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Malcolm I have updated my answer. This is for SageMath version 9.3 (the downsides of having a Windows machine), but seeing as it now does not depend on any assumptions/hidden order of elements anymore, it should work for any version.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciate it.